# Equation of circle - from chord

Tags: circles

Question:
If one of the diameters of the circle $x^2 + y^2-2x-6y+6 = 0$ is a chord to the circle with center (2, 1), then the radius of the circle is:

$\sqrt3,\sqrt2,3,2$

I have no clue as to where to begin this question. I tried drawing a diagram, but that didn't help me.

Comment: Do you want the radius of the circle $x^2+y^2-2x-6y+6 = 0$ or the radius of the circle centered at $(2,1)$? I'd have to guess the second option, but this is not clear from the wording of the question.

Answer (score 2):

So, the radius of the given circle $=\sqrt{1^2+3^2-6}=2$

Using  [Perpendicular Bisector of Chord Passes Through Centre](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Perpendicular_Bisector_of_Chord_Passes_Through_Center)

Observe that the distance between the two centres , this radius($=2$) & the other radius(hypotenuse) form a Pythagorean triangle